# Getting absolute 'top' position from a mouse event (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

On a mouseenter/mouseleave event, I would like to capture the absolute 'top' position of the cell of a table.

So far, the event is attached like so:

```
$('td[someAttr]').mouseenter(function(mouse) {
   // how do we get the td's top absolute position?

   //FYI: mouse.pageX and mouse.pageY would give the mouse position
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).offset().top
```

Comment: This will not give that absolute top; it'll give the position relative to its parent element; see http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/position

Comment: yeah i changed to offset before your comment & answer